# Invalid results when multiplying quaternions and no idea why

Tags: java, math, quaternions

I am currently working on a 3D-library including quaternions. As every expert, I coded my methods based on what I found on Wikipedia and it doesn't work quite right.

### This is the method for calculating the product between two quaternions:

```
public static Quaternion product(Quaternion a, Quaternion b) {
    return a.clone().multiply(b);
}
```

### And here is its implementation:

```
public Quaternion multiply(Quaternion q) {
    float rx = q.getX(), ry = q.getY(), rz = q.getZ(), rw = q.getW();

    this.w = w*rw - x*rx - y*ry - z*rz;
    this.x = w*rx + x*rw + y*rz - z*ry;
    this.y = w*ry - x*rz + y*rw + z*rx;
    this.z = w*rz + x*ry - y*rx + z*rw;
    return this;
}
```

### And here is a small test that I wrote:

```
Quaternion a = Quaternion.create(1, 1, 1, Spatium.DEG_TO_RAD *  15);
Quaternion b = Quaternion.create(1, 1, 1, Spatium.DEG_TO_RAD *  15);
Quaternion c = Quaternion.product(a, b);
System.out.println(a + " * " + b + " = " + c);
```

Note that the `create()` method initializes quaternions with `x`, `y`, `z`, `w`.

Unfortunately, the tests yields results that don't make any sense despite my amazing skills of copying and pasting Wikipedia formulas:

`(0.2617994 + 1.0i + 1.0j + 1.0k) * (0.2617994 + 1.0i + 1.0j + 1.0k) = (-2.931461 + -2.6696618i + 1.0j + -6.3393235k)`

For comparison, Wolfram solves it correctly and returns `-2.93146 + 0.523599i + 0.523599j + 0.523599k`.

Here's the formulas I so skillfully copied from Wikipedia:
[image]

I don't really have anything to say other than please help me, Wikipedia couldn't.

Comment: You can use some reference implementation to debug and verify your own code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should store the current values of `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` in a temp variable before updating it with new values.

```
    public Quaternion multiply(Quaternion q) {
        float rx = q.getX(), ry = q.getY(), rz = q.getZ(), rw = q.getW();

        float cx = x; // cx = current X
        float cy = y;
        float cz = z;
        float cw = w;

        this.w = cw*rw - cx*rx - cy*ry - cz*rz;
        this.x = cw*rx + cx*rw + cy*rz - cz*ry;
        this.y = cw*ry - cx*rz + cy*rw + cz*rx;
        this.z = cw*rz + cx*ry - cy*rx + cz*rw;
        return this;
    }
```

In your code, when you use `this.w = w*rw - x*rx - y*ry - z*rz;`, you are overridind the current value of `w`, and the next 3 operations will be affected by this changes.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Sometimes it's the most simple things we don't see. Guess I am not as good at copying from Wikipedia as I thought ...